# "[BABEL] Cannot find module" on a fresh PC install

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm setting up my dev environment on a fresh system. In my project folder:

```
npm install
npm run serve
```

And got this:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/src/main.js: Cannot find module '@babel/compat-data/corejs3-shipped-proposals'
Require stack:
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/polyfills/corejs3/usage-plugin.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-app/index.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/index.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js (While processing: "/Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset.js")
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/polyfills/corejs3/usage-plugin.js:10:55)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/project/editor/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:29:44)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.105:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I checked in node_modules/@babel/compat-data/ and the module is there. Why doesn't webpack (is it webpack?) see it?

Note that I did the same thing on another system a few weeks ago and it worked fine.
I also have a vuepress project on the same new system and it also runs fine.

Thanks

Comment: Tried `rm -r node_modules && npm install`?

Comment: Yep tried that.

Comment: Nice meme there.

Comment: huh what meme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can remove the lock files generated (package-lock.json)
and then remove the node modules from your project.**

And then again try to download the dependencies via npm
as  **npm install**

Answer (score 3):

In project folder:

```
rm package_lock.json
rm -r node_modules
npm install
```

Turns out I had package_lock.json on git from another system. Removed it and it worked.